# What time zone are due dates in?

Tags: trello

When setting a due date, what is the time zone for which you are setting it? Is it possible for each user to have their own time zone so that when a team member in one zone sets a deadline the correct date/time is reflected for all other users on the team?

Answer (score 18):

Trello stores the due dates in [**UTC**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), however it displays (and interprets) due dates in your local timezone (i.e. whatever your OS/Browser are set to), so the due date will be correct for your entire team, no matter what time zone they're in.

---

Here's an example of how this would work:

Suppose you are in New York, and you set the Due Date for the "Finish the slides for the presentation" card to **4:00 PM EDT**, so they'll be ready for a 4:00 PM meeting.

New York is using [EDT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone) (**UTC-4**), so Trello will interpret (and store) that 4:00PM as **8:00 PM UTC**.
(`8:00 PM UTC - 4 hours = 4:00 PM EDT`)

If the person responsible for finishing the slides is in California, which is using [PDT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_Time_Zone) (**UTC-7**) then when Trello displays the card for them, the due date will appear as **1:00 PM PDT**.
(`8:00 PM UTC - 7 hours = 1:00 PM PDT`)

If they finish the slides at 12:55PM PDT (5 minutes before the deadline) and email them to you, and it takes the email 1 minute to arrive in your inbox, you'll see it arrive at 3:56 PM EDT, just in time!

Comment: Except there appears to be no way to specify the timezone I want when I set the due date. So if I'm in Sydney and I want the due date to be PDT at 8am I have to calculate what that is in Sydney time myself and use the calculated time. Painful.