# How do I change the timezone in Trello notification emails?

Tags: trello

I've started using Trello to manage some projects and I just received my first email notification:

```
CARD on BOARD is due tomorrow at fri nov 30 2012 07:00:00 gmt-0500 (est)
```

I'm in the UK, so currently in the GMT timezone. When I look at the board itself the time for this task shows correctly as

```
CARD on BOARD is due tomorrow at 12.00pm
```

How do I get emails to send with the correct timezone as well?

Comment: Check out [the answers on this question](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/24741/what-time-zone-are-due-dates-in) ... does that answer your question?

Comment: @JoelSpolsky thanks, but that only says about how timezones are calculated in your browser, not in emails. In my browser the times display as expected (in GMT), but then the emails refer to EST...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved at some point since I posted this question. I now get due dates coming up in my local timezone - however I'm not sure how it knows this to be honest as in the front end it uses the browser settings - perhaps it logs these and uses that for emails?