# Incorrect due date on Trello

Tags: trello, trello-cards

For explanation purposes let's say my timezone is `GMT-3` or also called `America/Sao_Paulo` and I have the following date and time in Portuguese: `segunda, 2 Mai 2016, 23:55 BRT` which translates to `Monday, 2 May 2016, 23:55 BRT`.

I can easily convert it to `datetime.datetime` using [dateparser](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io):

```
import pytz
from dateparser import parse

str_date = 'segunda, 2 Mai 2016, 23:55 BRT'

dt = parse(str_date, languages=['pt'], settings={'TIMEZONE': 'America/Sao_Paulo', 'RETURN_AS_TIMEZONE_AWARE': True})
print(dt, type(dt))  # returns: datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 2, 23, 55, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Sao_Paulo' BRT-1 day, 21:00:00 STD>) <class 'datetime.datetime'>

dt_in_utc = dt.astimezone(pytz.timezone('UTC'))
print(dt_in_utc, type(dt_in_utc))  # returns: datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 3, 2, 55, tzinfo=<UTC>) <class 'datetime.datetime'>

dt_in_utc_tsp = dt_in_utc.timestap()
print(dt_in_utc_tsp, type(dt_in_utc_tsp))  # returns: 1462244100.0 <class 'float'>

trello.cards.update_due(card["id"], datetime.utcfromtimestamp(dt_in_utc_tsp))
```

Trello due date API can be [found here](https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/card#put-1-cards-card-id-or-shortlink-due), and according to [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/24741/what-time-zone-are-due-dates-in), Trello store due dates in UTC format.

Trello always displays dates on the cards using the users' timezone, in my case `GMT-3 America/Sao_Paulo`, the date on the card should be the same as the original, `2 May 2016, 23:55` but that's **not** what happens, instead I get `3 May 2016, 3:55` on the card. What's wrong?

---

**UPDATE #1**: This is the JSON that `trello.cards.update_due(card["id"], datetime.utcfromtimestamp(dt_in_utc_tsp))` returns (personal data removed):

```
{'badges': {'attachments': 1,
            'checkItems': 0,
            'checkItemsChecked': 0,
            'comments': 0,
            'description': False,
            'due': '2016-05-03T06:55:00.000Z',
            'fogbugz': '',
            'subscribed': False,
            'viewingMemberVoted': False,
            'votes': 0},
 'checkItemStates': [],
 'closed': False,
 'dateLastActivity': '2016-05-28T15:35:18.708Z',
 'desc': '',
 'descData': None,
 'due': '2016-05-03T06:55:00.000Z',
 'email': None,
 'id': '--removed--',
 'idAttachmentCover': None,
 'idBoard': '--removed--',
 'idChecklists': [],
 'idLabels': ['--removed--'],
 'idList': '--removed--',
 'idMembers': [],
 'idShort': 83,
 'labels': [--removed--],
 'manualCoverAttachment': False,
 'name': '--removed--',
 'pos': 131071.5,
 'shortUrl': '--removed--',
 'url': '--removed--'}
```

From this JSON I can guess that they store it like `2016-05-03T06:55:00.000Z`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ISO 8601 format for dates in the Trello API. In Python:

datetime.isoformat()

Comment: AMAZING. Worked like a charm. For anyone wondering, the correct code in my case would be: `trello.cards.update_due(card["id"], datetime.utcfromtimestamp(utc_tsp).isoformat())`. Thanks!